# How to run the a function on all the rows in a column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to format a specific column on my table in React and not sure how I would go about doing that. I have a function that formats the text in the column to the correct value but it only runs on the first index. I'm not sure how I would go about setting up a loop or a unique Id values on the table.

Here's my code. I'm trying to run FormatMgrName() on each row/column where the id = "mgr".

```
const Employees = () => {
    const [employeeTable, setEmployeeTable] = useState([]);
    const [employee, error, loading] = useAxios({
        axiosInstance: axios,
        method: "GET",
        url: '/?user=DoeJ@company.com',
        requestConfig: {
            headers: {
                'Content-Language': 'en-US'
            },
            
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (employee.length === 0) {
            console.log("DATA LOADING")
        } else {
            console.log("DATA LOADED")
            setEmployeeTable(employee.data.reports)
            console.log(employeeTable)
            if (employeeTable.length === 0) {
                console.log("TABLE NOT POPULATED")
            } else {
                FormatMgrName();
            }
        }
    });
    

    const CreateTable = () => {
        
        return (
            <table className="table-styled" id="EmpTable">
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Office Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Manager</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Profit Center</th>
                    <th>Department Head</th>
                    <th>Due</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {employeeTable.map((emp) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={emp.index}>
                                <td>{emp.lastFirst}</td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                <td id="mgr">{emp.mgrdn}</td>
                                <td>{emp.incomplete}</td>
                                <td>{emp.mail}</td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                <td>{emp.deptupn}</td>
                                <td>{emp.assignmentduedate}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }

    function FormatMgrName() {
        var name = document.getElementById("mgr").innerHTML
        var result = name.split(',')[0].split('=')[1];
        document.getElementById("mgr").innerHTML = result;
    }

    


    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Grid container direction="row">
                <Grid item>         
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{border: 1, borderColor: 'red'} }>
                        <HeaderObject />
                        <CreateTable />
                    </Container>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Employees
```

Comment: You've got a weird mix of native JS DOM, and React. They will conflict. Just create a function that accepts a string and returns a changed string, and then call it like `{formatMgrName(emp.mgrdn)}` in the `map` loop. Note: it looks like you'll also need `employee` in the dependency array for that `useEffect` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the function inside the braces itself with the value and return what you would like to show.
Put the function inside the create table before return

```
<td id="mgr">{this.FormatMgrName(emp.mgrdn)}</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2v17afqh/

- refer to formatText function inside this.

Comment: OP isn't using a class component so you won't need `this`.